# Android Keyboard Issue

Tags: android, keyboard, listener

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


   // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
   if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

I want to detect keyboard visibility at run time. The code above is not working in android 2.2. I need a solution for a keyboard event listener.

I have also added configChanges property in manifest.xml

Comment: this code is not for Keyboard visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pain point in Android.  You'll want to use a custom view as your root view and apply a listener that uses onSizeChanged() + the difference in layout change to call a custom callback.

Example view.

```
/**
 * Subclass of RelativeLayout that adds a size changed listener.  This is useful for determining
 * when the onscreen keyboard has popped up and resized the window
 *
 */
public class SCRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
  public interface OnSizeChangedListener {
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh);
  }

  private OnSizeChangedListener mOnSizeChangedListener;

  public SCRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public SCRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public SCRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if (mOnSizeChangedListener != null) {
      mOnSizeChangedListener.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
  }

  public void setOnSizeChangedListener(OnSizeChangedListener listener) {
    mOnSizeChangedListener = listener;
  }
}
```

Comment: Make this your root view in the layout, and in the onCreate for your activity, set a listener object to it using the defined methods.  It will call your method when the layout changes and you can compare sizes.